# My ubuntu theme GNOME shell is broken?

Tags: gnome, command-line, window-buttons

Hello fellow Ubuntu users, I've ran in to a problem.
I'm sorry if I'm not using the right therms, but it seems that the shell of my ubuntu is broken, I've lost the 3 graphic ways of (windows-buttons) resizing and minimize my windows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZzQB.png (sorry I can't post images since spam protections says that I'm a noob)

The problem is that I cant minimize m empathy chat windows, and the same goes for my skype. I have to Alt+F4 them to close the windows, but sometimes I just want to minimize them.. please help me out?

I did try to change shell and back to GNOME, but it did not help really :(

Comment: That looks Like Unity not Gnome Shell, into which session are you loggin?

Comment: Ah that explains it, I deleted some Unity lens.. I'm using the standard account and that is the only account.. I guess it will be complicated to restore,

Answer (score 1):

Try installing compizconfig settings manager through the software center.  Open the program and navigate to "Effects," and enable "Window Decoration."  You may then logout then login, or open the terminal and type

> unity --reset

This should give you the maximize, minimize, resize back.

Comment: Ah that explains it, I deleted some Unity lens.. I'm using the standard account and that is the only account.. I guess it will be complicated to restore,..

Comment: I tried the unity --reset thing, this was the reply from therminal window: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity", line 222, in <module>
    reset_unity_compiz_profile ()
  File "/usr/bin/unity", line 99, in reset_unity_compiz_profile
    subprocess.Popen(["metacity", "--replace"]) #TODO: check if compiz is indeed running
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: compiz -> effects it does not contain any option called Windows Decoration.. maybe its really deleted :(

Comment: ok found windows decoration when I did a search for it.. and it was already enabled.. I'll log off and on and see if it helps

Comment: I have restarted, and its the same.. I was trying to remove a lens using software center, I did a search for its name, and deleted a few files.. :/ so its my bad..